# Detect end of implicit animation when changing the UICollectionViewLayout

Tags: objective-c, ios, uicollectionview

I am currently working with UICollectionView and after changing the layout from one to another with setCollectionViewLayout:animated: I want to execute some code upon the completion of the animation. Any idea how to achieve that?

Cheers,

Comment: I solved my problem by changing the order of animations such that the one for switching the layout is invoked in the completion block of the last one and solved my problem. It's also interesting to note that if we have a standard UIView animationWithDuration... followed by the switch of layouts with its implicit one, the two animations take place simultaneously if the duration of the former one is proper. Nevertheless it would be interesting to know if there is any delegate method or way to assign a completion method that gets invoked once the switching animation is executed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that to be able to control the animation, rather than using the implicit one with `setCollectionViewLayout:animated:` you can use a standard UIView `animationWithDuration` and change the layout in the `animations` block, like this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.4
                      delay:0
                    options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                 animations:^{
                     self.oldView.collectionViewLayout = self.otherLayout;
                     self.newView.alpha = 1.0;
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     self.oldView.alpha = 0.0;
                     self.otherLayout = nil;
                 }];
```

I don't know if it is the recommended way to do it but it lets you control the animation and execute code upon completion.

Comment: I'll keep it in mind and give it a try when I'm in the situation of having to do it this way.

Comment: adding the option UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState seems to help. otherwise the animation can be very different then setCollectionViewLayout:animated

Answer (score 4):

Just for the record, there is now a `-setCollectionViewLayout:animated:completion:` method on `UICollectionView`, introduced in iOS 7.